# Limiting print output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a number of objects that I need to print out to the terminal (for debugging). The normal `print` function is almost perfect, except that some objects are too large, so `print` would create millions of lines of output. I'd like to create a function that does what `print` does, except that the output is truncated after a predefined number of characters, replacing the rest with `...`.

What's a good way to do that?

Note that performance is a concern, so ideally I'd prefer not to save a gigabyte-sized string and then take the first few characters from it; similarly, `pprint` is a bit of a problem since it sorts keys in dictionaries (and with millions of keys it takes a while).

Example:

```
obj = [ [1, 2, 3], list(range(1000000)) ]
my_print(obj, 20)
# should output:
# [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2...
```

Python 3, if it matters.

Comment: If you have dictionaries with nesting, probably [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pprint.html) with parameter `depth` set will help?

Comment: @myaut it's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: You can define your own representation with [`reprlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/reprlib.html).

Comment: @m0nhawk I think this is it. Can you please move it from a comment to an answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`reprlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/reprlib.html) module (Python 3.x only) suggested by @m0nhawk is made exactly for this purpose. Here's how you would use it:

If you're fine with the **default limits**, you can simply use [`reprlib.repr(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.repr):

```
import reprlib

obj = [[1, 2, 3], list(range(10000))]

print(reprlib.repr(obj))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]]
```

---

In order to **customize the [available limits](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#repr-objects)**, simply create a `reprlib.Repr` instance and set the appropriate instance attributes:

```
r = reprlib.Repr()
r.maxlist = 4       # max elements displayed for lists
r.maxstring = 10    # max characters displayed for strings

obj = [[1, 2, 3], list(range(10000)), 'looooooong string', 'a', 'b', 'c']

print(r.repr(obj))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, ...], 'lo...ing', 'a', ...]
```

---

If you're dealing with sequence **objects that refer to themselves**, you can use `Repr.maxlevel` to limit the recursion depth:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst.append(lst)  # oh my!

r = reprlib.Repr()
r.maxlevel = 5   # max recursion depth

print(r.repr(lst))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [...]]]]]]
```

---

Note that `reprlib.repr()` *returns* a string, but doesn't `print` it (unless you're in an interactive console where the result of every expression you enter gets evaluated and its representation displayed).

Answer (score 3):

Why not just make a simple slice wrapper over the `print` function?

```
def my_print(obj, depth):
    print(str(obj)[:depth])
```

`print` does the same thing as `str` before writing to the output stream. So what you want to do is do that casting early, before passing it into print, and then slice off a chunk of it that has a max size of whatever you want.

Python slicing is graceful, so a string slice like `'xyz'[:30000]` evaluates simply to `'xyz'` rather than raising an error.

Comment: This would work perfectly, except it would still take forever to run. I have dictionaries with hundreds of thousands of keys, whose values are lists with hundreds of items. Converting those to `str` will take a very long time, so ideally I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: @max I think the call to `str` is pretty much unavoidable. You could try changing what `str` does by looking into Python's special methods system and `__str__`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__ However, a big problem is that you can't change the attributes of built-in types like `dict`. I think you might be stuck with implementing your own wrapper class over dict and then overriding its `__str__` function with your own custom one.