# In IDLE, what is the simplest way to limit the number of lines displayed by a pprint call?

Tags: python, dictionary, large-data, python-idle, pprint

I am working with large nested dictionaries in Python and would like to quickly check their structure in IDLE.  The [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module nicely displays this structure, but leads IDLE to hang due to the size the variables.  Is there a simple way to limit the number of lines that `pprint` prints, or similarly limit the number of key-value pairs displayed at each level of structure?  (I may be missing something obvious here.)

Of note, [there appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321969/limiting-print-output) to be a [reprlib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/reprlib.html) module made for the similar goal of truncating the output of `print` after a certain number of characters.  However, `print` does not display the structure of large nested dictionaries in a readable fashion, so this module seems to be impractical for my purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by crash?  I have printed half a million normal lines in IDLE without a problem.  Super-long lines over 2000 chars will make it increasingly sluggish.  But it should not actually quit.  I don't know more about pprint than what is in the doc.

Comment: Crash may be the wrong word -- I've edited my question.  IDLE will produce output for a little while, and then the window will freeze and indicate that the program is not responding.  Indeed when printing medium-sized variables, the pprint operation can actually complete from this state if I do nothing.  Printing my large variables, however, would take hours to days at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could format the data to a string, split it into lines, and print only as many as desired:

```
for line in pprint.pformat(data).splitlines()[:42]:
    print(line)
```

Instead of slicing, you could also just print *all* lines and stop with Ctrl-C when you've seen enough.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing around with your problem. Would printing a truncated dictionary instead accomplish what you need? Here I applied a technique from [tutorialsport](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-truncate-a-Python-dictionary-at-a-given-length)

```
import itertools                                                                
import pprint                                                                   
                                                                                
# An arbitary, nested dictionary                                                
nested_inner = {i: ['a', 'b', 'c'] for i in range(5)}                           
nested_mid = {chr(i): nested_inner for i in range(65, 70)}                      
nested_outer = {i: nested_mid for i in range(10000)}                            
                                                                                
# truncate the dictionary instead?                                              
sample_data = dict(itertools.islice(nested_outer.items(), 500))                 
                                                                                
pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4, width=80, depth=3)                               
pprint.pprint(sample_data)
```

Comment: That looks promising. For the dictionaries I am working with, some of the inner levels are large.  For instance, we could replace range(5) with range(50000) in your example. Is there an extension or variant of this approach for that case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried either reducing the nesting by setting the `depth` parameter or setting `compact=True`? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Comment: Yes, unfortunately neither of these parameters works for the purpose.  I want to see the nested dictionary structure at full depth (which in one case is given by just depth=3).  And compact=True appears to have no effect at all on my output.  In principle, this parameter setting would place many items on one line when the width permits this, but in my case this would both make the output more crowded and would still be insufficient to keep IDLE from stalling (since output length/n where n is a modest integer is still large).